# How to use Databinding in MaterialAlertDialog?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-alertdialog, android-databinding

I would like to use databinding in my MaterialAlertDialog in order to change the text while my dialog is showing, but there are literally zero tutorials covering this. Does somebody has any idea doing this?

### Dialog Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="loginUserId"
            type="String" />
        <variable
            name="loginOperation"
            type="String" />
    </data>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/materialTextView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:text="Example Verifizierung:"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textDescriptionNormal2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/progressBar" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/materialTextView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:text="@{loginUserId}"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textDescriptionNormal2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView2" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/materialTextView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/big16dpMargin"
            android:text="@{loginOperation}"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textDescriptionNormal2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/materialTextView3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView3" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

### Dialog Builder

```
fun Fragment.buildLoginDialog() {
    return MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext(), R.style.LoginDialogTheme)
        .setTitle(R.string.loading_login_title)
        .setView(R.layout.login_loading_screen)
        .setCancelable(true)
}
```

### Fragment (what I want)

```
// Somewhere in fragment
val dialog = buildLoginDialog()

private fun observerSignInStatus() {
    loginViewModel.signInResult.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { status ->
        dialog.show()
        when(status) {
            is LoginStateEvent.Loading -> {
                dialog.changeText(status.message)
            }
            is LoginStateEvent.LoggedIn -> {
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
            is LoginStateEvent.Error -> {
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Dialog Picture

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to find a solution, without creating a dialogFragment. In fact, it IS possible to use databinding in a Alertdialog with ease. I am not 100% if my implementation of the lifecycleowner is correct, tho.

### Implementation

```
class CustomDialog(context: Context, private val mLifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner): AlertDialog(context, R.style.LoginDialogTheme) {
    private var _binding: LoginLoadingScreenBinding? = null
    private val binding: LoginLoadingScreenBinding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        initDialog()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun show() {
        _binding = LoginLoadingScreenBinding.inflate(layoutInflater).apply { lifecycleOwner = mLifecycleOwner }
        super.show()
    }

    override fun dismiss() {
        _binding = null
        super.dismiss()
    }

    fun onChangeUserId(mText: String) {
        binding.userId.text = mText
    }

    fun onChangeLoginOperation(mText: String) {
        binding.loginOperation.text = mText
    }

    private fun initDialog() {
        setTitle(R.string.loading_login_title)
        setCancelable(true)
        setView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

### Calling Side

```
// fragment
val dialog = CustomDialog(requireContext(), viewLifecyleOwner)

dialog.show()
dialog.onChangeUserId("New Id")
dialog.OnChangeLoginOperation("New Operation")
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options here. You can create a class that inherits from the `DialogFragment`. `Dialogfragments` are useful to show more complex layouts in a dialog way, allowing you to control and manipulate your custom layout. They act like regular Fragment, meaning you have to override `onCreateView()` & `onViewCreated()` to display your custom view by using `databinding`.

Or

You create a class that inherits from `DialogFragment` again but now you will need to override  the `onCreateDialog()` to make it use `onCreateView()` & `onViewCreated()` to display and manage the Fragment's layout, like this:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext(), theme).apply {
            dialogView = onCreateView(LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()), null, savedInstanceState)

            dialogView?.let { onViewCreated(it, savedInstanceState) }
            setView(dialogView)
        }.create()
    }
```

Then you need  also:

```
override fun getView(): View? { return dialogView   }
```

Comment: But I don't want to use a dialogfragment, a normal AlertDialog is all I need. The Loading screen should not cover all the surface

Comment: I think you can't use the builder with databinding. Thats why you have the dialogfragments. It won't cover all the surface since you create a dialog by using a dialogfragment. Maybe I don't get your point here.

Comment: I don't think that I can use a dialogfragment either: With this, I would have two fragments and couldn't change the value at all. I would observe a viewmodel value from Fragment A and try to change the binding value from Fragment A  in my DialogFragment. Thats not possible...

Comment: So let me get this straight. You have a fragment where you observe the login status and you display a dialog that shows that status and you want to update that status when it gets updated in the fragment right? It has nothing to do with databinding in the alertdialog right ? The way you present the problem is a bit confusing that's why I'm asking.

Comment: yeah you got it. I have a fragment where I am observing a login status, the dialog should show the status and I want to update the dialog when the status gets updated.

Comment: Okay that makes sense now. You still need a custom dialog imo and you could use broadcastchannel/stateflow if you work with coroutines and collect  the status in the dialog and then update the text or dismiss it or whatever you want.